# After unistalling python tkinter it continuous to work

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Python 3.9 on Windows 10 with IDLE. To debug a problem that I have in my larger code, I unistalled tinker using the "pip uninstall tk" command and it was uninstalled successfuly. To double check that it was uninstalled I tried to uninstal it again and I got an error with a message that tk is uninstalled. However when I run the example program below, it works perfect as if tkinter was not unistalled. How can it be?

```
import  pandas as pd
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# Import the Excel spreadsheet into a Pandas data frame
# and use a windows dialog box to select the file name.

filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
df = pd.read_excel (filename)
print (df)
```

Comment: Tkinter is included with installs of Python.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to either install or uninstall it? Why do you want to unintall it?

Comment: I was aware that Tkinter is included with installs of Python however I wanted to uninstall it to debug a problem  in my complex program. What puzzles me is that I could uninstall Tkinter as I described abioove, veify that it was uninstalled,  and yet it works as it was not uninstalled.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/#pip-uninstall 
You can see that you are not able to delete a built in module using pip.

Comment: maybe you can try to update your pip and try again.
this is what I saw when I did `pip uninstall tk` in the terminal: `WARNING: Skipping tk as it is not installed.`

Comment: The only way I could see `Successfully uninstalled tk-0.1.0` is by install tk using pip and then uninstall it.

Comment: When I previously uninstalled tk, I received exactly the same warning: WARNING: Skipping tk as it is not installed. I will try to install it again and unistall it.

Comment: I installed tk and uninstalled it again. It did not help. It looks like you were right from the beginning, PIP is unable to uninstall tkinter. I will have to find another way to debug my more complex program. I think that the reason for not allowing the user to uninstall tk is that some other libraries are tk in the background. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that the `tk` module installed by `pip` is not tkinter.  It is a module called "TensorKit".

Comment: If you want to simulate there is no `tkinter` module, create `tkinter.py` inside your project folder with content `raise ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'tkinter'")`.

Comment: Thnak you so much for pointing it out. Now evrything makes sense. However, how do you explain that my example program does accept importing tkinter.

Comment: @acw1668 you are right, `pip install tk` installs "TensorKit"!

Comment: @Menachem It is because `tkinter` is included when you install Python.

Comment: _""pip uninstall tk" command and it was uninstalled successfully. "_ -if that worked, it uninstalled something other than tkinter. The tkinter module is named `tkinter`, and it cannot be installed or uninstalled with pip.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot unistall tk using `pip uninstall tk`. The only way you can do this is by deleting `tk` directory.

Path to `tk` can be found by running this script:

```py
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tcl_library'))
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tk_library'))
```

In my case this was:
`C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/tcl/tk8.6`

To delete just delete the `tk8.6` folder by typing this commands in powershell

```
cd C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/tcl/
rm tk8.6
```